# get return type from a function of a class that was forward-ed declaraion

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-declaration, decltype, pimpl-idiom

Is it possible to get return type `UglyIterator<>` of a function of a class `B::f`  which is forward declaration?

### Example

`MyArray` is a class that acts like `std::vector`.
Its `begin()` and `end()` function return a ugly type.

```
template<class T> class MyArray{
     UglyIterator<Protocol1,Protocol2,SafetyFlag,brabrabra> begin(){
         //some code
     }
     //... other functions ....
};
```

`B` has `MyArray<int>` as a **value** field.
With the magic of **auto-keyword**, `B` can pretend to be a neat class.

```
#include "MyArray.h"
class B{  //just a bundle of data
    MyArray<int> bField;
    public: auto f(){  //<--- neat     
        return bField.begin();
    }
    //... other fields  ...
};
```

`Manager` is a manager of `B` and do other things.

```
#include "B.h"
class Manager{  //just a bundle of data
    decltype(&B::f) mField;  //I can cache it, so neat!
    //^ actually it is "UglyIterator<Protocol1,Protocol2,SafetyFlag,brabrabra>"
    //... other functions/fields ...
};
```

As project grow, I noticed that `Manager.h` was included in many files, and `MyArray`'s code changed very often.

To reduce compile time, I decided to **forward declaration** at `Manager`.
I changed `mField` to `mFieldPtr`, but I get compile error :-

```
class B;
class Manager{  
    std::unique_ptr<std::result_of<decltype(&B::f)>::type> mFieldPtr; 
    //^ should compile error (can not recognize "B::f")
    //... other functions ...
};
```

How to get the return type `decltype(&B::f)` elegantly?

### My workaround

Create a new file `B_TopHeader.h`.

```
using B_F_returnType = UglyIterator<Protocol1,Protocol2,SafetyFlag,brabrabra>;
//^ the type "UglyIterator" also need another forward declaration
```

Then let the `Manager` `#include` `B_TopHeader.h` instead :-

```
#include "B_TopHeader.h"
class Manager{  
    std::unique_ptr< B_F_returnType > mFieldPtr;
    //... other functions ...
};
```

However, I think it is not elegant.    It seems to be a hack.
I have to *forward* the return type manually.

Comment: You may use [pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to hide member of `Manager`.

Comment: The type of `&B::f` is not `UglyIterator<…>`, but `UglyIterator<...> (B::*)()`. Do you want the return type or member function pointer type?

Comment: @kennytm  Sorry, I will edit it.  I want return type.  Thank.

Comment: @Jarod42   very good idea .....  it might be a perfect solution ... create a new class `Manager2` that  `#include "B.h"`, and let `Manager` store `Manager2*`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to hide the dependency, something like:

```
class Manager
{
public:
    ~Manager() noexcept; // you certainly have also to handle copy/move

    // Stuff using mFieldPtr, but which doesn't return it.
private:
    std::unique_ptr<struct Impl> mImpl;
};
```

And in cpp

```
#include "Manager.h"
#include "B.h"

struct Manager::Impl
{
    // Implementation using mField

    decltype(&B::f) mField;
};


Manager::~Manager() noexcept = default;

// Forward methods of `Manager` to `Impl`.
```